# How to edit the attributes of an inherited class without initializing a new class in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, attributes

My question shows the problem pretty well, so I will go straight to the code.

```
class Boxer:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.health = 100
        self.damage = 20
        self.power = 30
```

here is the original or parent class

```
class Prince(Boxer):
    self.damage = 40
    self.health = 80
```

What I am trying to do is inherit most of the class attributes, and only edit these 2 (damage, health), is there any way to do this without having to create a whole other class?

Comment: Are you asking whether you can write a class that inherits from another class without writing a class?

Comment: Please do not ask readers not to refer you to other questions. If someone believes this is a duplicate, they may have found something that you did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so two things are not quite right here. First off, the code for `Prince` - `self` can only be used inside methods, like the constructor. The attributes for Prince should actually look like:

```
class Prince(Boxer):
    damage = 40
    health = 80
```

Second, the constructor in `Boxer` is going to overwrite those default values when it is called. So, for those to be overrideable, you need to set the attributes in the class definition, not the constructor:

```
class Boxer:
    health = 100
    damage = 20
    power = 30

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

That should get you somewhere to working as you intended.

**EDIT**

If you really don't want to use a subclass for every type of boxer, an alternative could be to use default values in your constructor, and these can be overridden. So:

```
class Boxer:
    def __init__(self, name, health=100, damage=20, power=30):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage
        self.power = power
```

Then:

```
Boxer("Alan") # Ordinary boxer
Boxer("Prince", damage=40, health=80) # Prince is special
```

Comment: @roganjosh It wouldn't, but it's not clear if there is just one `Prince` or many from the question - from the context I think OP doesn't want to produce a brand new class for every instance, but I could be wrong. If there are multiple, distinct, Princes required, then yes, it should have its own class.

Comment: there would only be one, the user would select a class and name their character, however I felt  like creating classes for each playable _class_ would be the easiest to add in other attributes along the way